# How to remove Everyone permissions for NTFS and add Authenticated users

Tags: powershell, ntfs, smb

I have a script to remove Everyone permissions for NTFS and add Authenticated users, but I am using the SMB share to remove and add but that is not working for the Subfolders, can I do that using the ACL permissions instead of SMB shares.

**Code I have used**

```
$Server = "USATRAMEHK040.atrame.deloitte.com"

# Get all shares on the computer
#$Shares = Get-SmbShare
$Shares = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Server -Class win32_share -Filter "Description != 'Remote Admin' and Description != 'Default share' and Description != 'Remote IPC' and Description != 'Printer Drivers'" | Select-Object Name -ExpandProperty Name

# Loop through each share, check and remove Everyone permission
foreach ($Share in $Shares) {
  
  ## Creating folderpath variable
$FolderPath =  "\\$Server\$share"

 ## Get Root Folder Permissions
$Folders = @(Get-Item -Path $FolderPath | Select-Object Name,FullName,LastWriteTime,Length)

## Get Folders
$error.clear()
$Folders += Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Directory |  Select-Object Name,FullName,LastWriteTime,Length -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
foreach ($err in $Error) {
$err.Exception.Message | Out-File $ExportPath\AccessDenied.txt -Append
}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders){

  ## Get access control list
  $Acls = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

## Loop through ACL

# Get Access permissions for current share and filter only permissions for group "Everyone"
## Loop through ACL

  foreach ($Acl in $Acls.Access) {

$EveryonePermission =  ($Acl.IdentityReference -like "everyone")
  

  # If current share has permissions for Everyone, remove said permission
  if ($EveryonePermission) {

  Revoke-SmbShareAccess -name $Share -CimSession $Server -AccountName Everyone -Force
  Grant-SmbShareAccess -name $Share -CimSession $Server -AccountName Authenticated Users -AccessRight Full –Force
    #Get-SMBShare "\\$Server\$share" | Revoke-SMBShareAccess -AccountName "everyone"
    #Get-SMBShare "\\$Server\$share" | Grant-SMBShareAccess -Account "Username" -AccessRight "Full/Change/Read"   


    #Revoke-SmbShareAccess -Name $Share.Name -ScopeName $EveryonePermission.ScopeName -AccountName $EveryonePermission.AccountName -Force
    #Grant-SmbShareAccess $Share.Name -AccountName 'Authenticated Users' -AccessRight Full -Force
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would be great if someone can please help me achieve this...

Comment: How did you do it using SMB? Do you know that SMB support ACLs? and there is an inherit flag that you can set an ACL on a folder and all of its child objects will inherit the same ACL.

There are several opensource/commercial SMB libraries out there that provide ACL support (LSAR)